# How can I detect that no options were passed with getopts?

Tags: bash, shell, options, getopts

I have this code -

```
#getoptDemo.sh
usage()
{
    echo "usage: <command> options:<w|l|h>"
}
while getopts wlh: option
do
    case $option in
            (w)
                    name='1';;
            (l)
                    name='2';;
            (h)
                    name='3';;
            (*)
                    usage
                    exit;;
    esac
done
print 'hi'$name
```

When I run `bash getoptDemos.sh` (without the option) it prints `hi` instead of calling the function `usage`. It calls usage when options other than w, h and l are given. Then can't it work when no options are specified.

I have tried using `?`, `\?`, `:` in place of `*` but I can't achieve what I wanted to. I mean all the `docs` on `getopt` says it to use `?`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What shell are you running it under?

Comment: I am running it under `/bin/bash`

Comment: Other alternatives: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you run this script without any options, getopt will return false, so it won't enter the loop at all. It will just drop down to the print - is this ksh/zsh?

If you must have an option, you're best bet is to test $name after the loop.

```
if [ -z "$name" ]
then
   usage
   exit
fi
```

But make sure `$name` was empty before calling `getopts` (as there could have been a `$name` in the environment the shell received on startup) with

```
unset name
```

(before the `getopts` loop)

Comment: no. its bash. So how do i achieve what I want - handle the `no argument` condition using bash.

Comment: If you want a mandatory option, I don't think thats possible - its probably why they are called options :) 
You can test $name though, after the loop to make sure it has been set. 
if [ -z "$name" ] ; then usage; exit ; fi

Comment: thanks. the above code really helped. Its too bad `getopts` doesn't have such provision. What's worse than that is can't upvote you.

Comment: what if I was running other shell? zsh, sh. does any shell other than bash take care of this condition?

Answer (score 35):

`getopts` processes the options in turn. That's its job. If the user happens to pass no option, the first invocation of `getopts` exits the while loop.

If none of the options take an argument, the value of `OPTIND` indicates how many options were passed. In general, `OPTIND` is the number of arguments that are options or arguments to options, as opposed to non-option arguments (operands).

```
while getopts …; do …; done
if [ $OPTIND -eq 1 ]; then echo "No options were passed"; fi
shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "$# non-option arguments"
```

In any case, you're not trying to determine whether there were no options, but whether none of the `name`-setting options were passed. So [check if `name` is unset (and take care to unset it first)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50564).

Comment: thanks. +1 for you. when I put the last 3 lines from your code in sample.sh and run `bash sample.sh -abc file.txt` it gives - `1 non-option arguments`. how do I find out how many options were given. (here 3)

Comment: Strange no one has commented on this slight bug -- if no options are given, OPTIND will be 1 after that 'while getopts ...' loop.  Thus the if check should check equality with 1, not zero.

Answer (score 7):

I would check it with a variable. If getopts never passes the loop in case of no argument, you can use that for example like this:

```
#getoptDemo.sh
usage()
{
    echo "usage: <command> options:<w|l|h>"
}

no_args="true"
while getopts wlh: option
do
    case $option in
            (w)
                    name='1';;
            (l)
                    name='2';;
            (h)
                    name='3';;
            (*)
                    usage
                    exit;;
    esac
    no_args="false"
done

[[ "$no_args" == "true" ]] && { usage; exit 1; }

print 'hi'$name
```

Answer (score 4):

If your script must receive option arguments is any case, place this block in the beginning (before getops).

```
if [[ ! $@ =~ ^\-.+ ]]
then
  #display_help;
fi
```

Block checks that parameter string not begins with `-` symbol, what indicates that first parameter is not an option argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just before your `getopts` block, check to see if `$1` (the first argument/option you passed on the command line) is equal to an empty string. If it is, print the usage message and exit, (or execute some "no options" function if you're an anarchist), otherwise let `getopts` parse the options like normal.

The reason this feature isn't included in getopts, is because you can already accomplish it in bash with an "if-else". Example:

```bsh
if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
    Your_Usage_Function;
    exit;
else
   #parse options with getopts code block here;
fi
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You should always initialize your variables before using them!  This prevents already-set variables from screwing with your script, and additionally, it lets you check the status later on to ensure they were properly set.

```
#getoptDemo.sh
usage()
{
    echo "usage: <command> options:<w|l|h>"
}

name=false

while getopts wlh: option
do
    case $option in
            (w)
                    name='1';;
            (l)
                    name='2';;
            (h)
                    name='3';;
            (*)
                    usage
                    exit;;
    esac
done

if [[ $name == false ]]; then
    usage();
    exit 1;
fi

print 'hi'$name
```

Comment: you need to remove the () behind the usage call